# Groovy + Geb+Spock deploying on a windows server

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock, geb

Folks,

Thanks for the help , so currently I am building my automation in groovy + Spock+Geb and the current environment they are using windows server. So they have spun up a test server for me. My question is what is what is the norm out there when trying to get this on a server to run( NOT HEADLESS). Appeciate the help and advice, keep in mind they do not want any new techology stack introduce. I saw a few mentioned gradle just wondering the ease of use and running

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is definitely the way to go with this. With Gradle you can define various "tasks". these tasks might be different script executions or dependency downloads; its whatever you want them to be. Then from there you can execute these tasks from the command line on your windows server. Just call `gradlew.bat <task1> <task2>....`

Comment: Thank you @switch201 I don't know much about Gradle so I will start learning up so I can use gradle. Question for you, do you know if it has to be an executable to be used on the command line or a regular Jar when using gradle?

Comment: For windows I think you have to call "gradlew.bat" on the command line and that's all that will work, but I am no expert. gradlew.bat contains all the info on where to find your "JAVA_HOME" and such. If you need to download a jar and use it in a gradle project, you need to add it to your build.gradle file as a task for example: `dependencies { compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7' }` will download and index all of the groovy jars that Geb needs. I simply need to call `gradlew.bat dependencies' note you can have tasks that call other tasks too.

Comment: thank you, when you say command line u are speaking about cmd correct? I am guess gradle does not have its own command line.

Comment: Yes CMD is correct, but you have to be in the same directory as gradlew.bat or you have to specify the path. if my answer was sufficient, feel free to mark it as so :)

Comment: it is and I have marked it but my reputation is under 15 so it may not be recorded. Sorry about that and thanks for your help

Comment: No problem if you have any more question I would be happy to help, just message me.

Comment: ok @switch201 this is what I got so far, so I have a demo gradle project that I am using, it works perfect got off the forum, I am also run the build via the cmd , I ahve not been able to run that gradlew.bat off the cmd. I am not sure how I am going to get this gradle build project to be ran off my task scheduler. I tried doing and executable via gradle and creates it perfectly but having issues with the main class and manifest info. Is there a way to just run that gradlew.bat file via the task scheduler  and it runs everything or what do you suggest I do. Once again u have been tremdoushelp

Comment: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle   --- This the code sample I am using since it has everything that I am using in my current project(geb+spock etc).

Comment: now if I run the jar task it creates a jar and I added    jar{manifest{attributes 'Main-Class' : 'GebishOrgTest', 'ClassPath': '.'  ---So this is what I place into the build.gradle. I am not quite understanding how I can set the right manifest info so I can ran this as an executable jar on the windows server.

Comment: I am not sure I know enough to help you all the way, but in regards to running gradlew.bat, did you list your tasks after? for example `gradlew.bat build' will run the buildscript task. I am not sure I follow what you are saying about the manifest.

Comment: let me try that , I have no tasks currently and I think that is what is occuring, the manifest item I just figured out. Thanks

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND: The solution is that I were using GebReportinSpec extension which is limiting me to only using Junit since it runs off junit runner. So I changed the extension to use GebReportingTest which I can now run via JVM and export, I exported using eclipse export feature (had issues when exporting via gradle) and toss the jar on the task sch. No issues worked liked a charm. Now I will setup task like switch201 recommended.